Sphinx doc toctree click "jumps" to nav anchor instead of top
When I click a toctree (navbar) item, the page "jumps/jolts" to the toc element instead of the top of the new page as if it's aligning with the toctree anchor (instead of the body h1 or just generally to the top page):

This makes an unstable feeling for the page causing sudden jumps down the page.
If I'm scrolled all the way up before clicking and the body is a 1-pager, you can't repro this. However, if your body has a scrollbar, this is easily repro'd.
Expected: Clicking a toctree element should bump me to the top of the new page
Actual: I'm unexpectedly bumped down the new page to where the toctree element was anchored. New pages never start at the top, but 1/2 way down (unless it's a 1-pager doc).
Is there a way to stop navigating to the toctree anchor on click? I was expecting it to bump to the h1 or page top.
__
EDIT 1: TL;DR using this site as an example: When I click on StackOverflow "Questions" section, I can still see "Home" above (the body moved, but the navbar didn't move -- expected). In my Sphinx build, if I were to dupe StackOverflow's navbar and clicked "Questions", I could no longer see "Home" since the navbar would anchor down. (CC'd from comment that felt important enough to edit in here)
EDIT 2: Here's a GIF showing what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/oE25Siw.gif

Assuming you are using sphinx_rtd_theme, what you observe is expected behavior and by design. You could set the depth option to 1 so that no subheadings within a page show. However it sounds like you want subheadings to appear. Thus I would suggest you try a different theme, such us Furo, Sphinx Book Theme, or PyData Sphinx theme, which instead has an in-page contents navigation on the right side and page only navigation on the left.

Thanks @StevePiercy, however there may have been a misunderstanding: It's a bit hard to explain; trying a different way -- The navbar before clicked is perfect and I am happy with the subheadings and such. It's when I click it, the left navbar frame seems to anchor to the nav link clicked. It'd be like if you clicked the "Tags" in Stackoverflow and the left navbar would realign itself at that "tag" (hiding "Questions, Home". It makes navigation jolty and confusing. I don't want the navbar to jump to navbar anchor when clicked (only body anchors) [Edited for clarity]

TL;DR using this site as an example: When I click on StackOverflow "Questions" section, I can still see "Home" above (the body moved, but the navbar didn't move -- expected). In my Sphinx build, if I were to dupe StackOverflow's navbar and clicked "Questions", I could no longer see "Home" since the navbar would anchor down.

GIF: https://i.imgur.com/oE25Siw.gif

Fixed, following the lead of this post: (add smooth scroll-behavior css to html). The difference is huge:
https://i.imgur.com/OygLmHv.gif
Navigating to new pages are still "jerky" (in 1/4 second it jumps to top of nav then jumps back down), but no longer anchors to the navbar like it used to.
